# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined - React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am creating a website where the user can search for a query and the results are shown.

I have one component called: `Searchbar`which contains two functions:

1)
The user writes a query, which is sent via axios POST request to the backend when the user preses enter.

2) The backend search the relative query and sends the results back via axios GET request.

Therefore the order is: `postQuery()-->getQueryResult()` so I think that `postQuery()` creates a promise that, if resolved, allows `getQueryResult()` to run.
However I get:

> > TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
> >
> > Error on line 38: return postQuery(query).then(() => getQueryResult());

**My code is:**

```
function Searchbar() {

    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState(["myemptyinitiallist"]);

  function postQuery(query) {
    var myParams = {
         data: query
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/query', myParams)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log("Yes, it sends the query in JSON format to Flask");
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error, "Error on AXIOS post");
      });
  } // Enf of postQuery

  function getQueryResult() {
    (axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/query')
    .then(function (response) {
      setResults(response.data); //set the value
      console.log(results)
    }))
  } // End getQueryResult()

    function handleEnter(query){
        if (query != "") {
      return postQuery(query).then(() => getQueryResult());
    } else {
        alert("The search query cannot be empty")
      }
  } // End of function handleEnter()


    return(
    <div>
        <SearchBar
            onChange={(event) => setQuery(event)}
            onRequestSearch={() => handleEnter(query)}
            style={{
                marginTop: 200,
                marginLeft: 'auto',
                marginRight: 'auto',
                maxWidth: 800,
            }}
        />
      <ResultList/>
</div>
    )
}


export default Searchbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no return statement in `postQuery` so it returns `undefined`.
In addition, `catch` clauses fulfill their returned promise by default. To allow the return promise to be caught as well, rethrow the error in the `catch` callback.

Try

```
  function postQuery(query) {
    var myParams = {
         data: query
    }
    return axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/query', myParams)
      .then(function(response){
        console.log("Yes, it sends the query in JSON format to Flask");
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error, "Error on AXIOS post");
        throw error; // don't fulfill returned promise
      });
  } // End of postQuery
```

Comment: Thanks. However now when the user clicks `enter` the console.log shows that `results` it is not updated. Only after the second, third and so on `enter` the results are updated. I think it is still executing the `GET`before the `POST`. I want the `POST` before the `GET`

Comment: The client side promise code executes the `POST' in `postQuery` before the `GET` in `getQueryResult`. I would check that `setResults` is a synchronous operation first, and if so checking if  the results logged from a second  query are not those of the one before it - if they are the issue is with the design not covering separate asynchronous POST/GET requests for a single query. Please ask a new question with all the details you uncover if you are unable to resolve the new issues. Regards.